# NestJS Sequelize table insert/create not working

Tags: typescript, nestjs, sequelize-typescript

I am trying to build a small webserver with mysql database. For that I use NestJs with Sequelize but I'm just leraning it and can't find the error:

I have a datebase with one table:

```
import {Column, Model, Table, DataType} from "sequelize-typescript";

@Table
export class ShiftActivity extends Model{
  @Column({
    allowNull: false,
    autoIncrement: true,
    primaryKey:true,
    type: DataType.UUIDV4,
    defaultValue: DataType.UUIDV4,
  })
  id: string;

  @Column
  externalId: number;

  @Column
  name: string;

  @Column
  acronym: string;

  @Column
  rgbCode: string;
}
```

And this is my service class:

```
import {Injectable} from '@nestjs/common';
import {InjectModel} from '@nestjs/sequelize';
import {ShiftActivity} from './shift-activity.model';
import {Sequelize} from 'sequelize-typescript';

@Injectable()
export class ShiftsActivityService {
  constructor(
    @InjectModel(ShiftActivity)
    private shiftActivityTable: typeof ShiftActivity,
    private sequelize: Sequelize
  ) {
    this.shiftActivityTable.sync();
    this.init();
  }

  async init() {
    try {
      await this.shiftActivityTable.findAll().then(value => console.log(
        "findAll: ", value.toString()
      ));
      await this.create(
        "Verkauf",
        "V",
        "00ff00",
        null,
      ).then(value => console.log(
        "new Activity '", value.name, "' with id: ", value.id.toString(),)
      );
 
    }catch(e){
      console.log(e);
    }
  }

      async create(
        name: string,
        acronym: string,
        rgbCode: string,
        externalId: string | null | undefined = null,
      ): Promise<ShiftActivity> {
        try {
          let newAction;
          console.log("--\n  newAction\n--");
          await this.sequelize.transaction(async t => {
            const transactionHost = {transaction: t};
            newAction = await this.shiftActivityTable.create({
              externalId: -1,
              name: name,
              acronym: acronym,
              rgbCode: rgbCode,
            });
          });
          console.log("--\n  newAction\n--");
          return newAction;
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
      }
}
```

And I am trying to insert a first set of test data to build my API from there. The Inection and Moduls are working, a findAll() funktion works as it should. But the create() funktion throws an error, I can't find the source of.
The call of init() in the constructor gets me this output:

```
Executing (default): SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' AND TABLE_NAME = 'Shifts' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'pepzeit_dev'
Executing (default): SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' AND TABLE_NAME = 'ShiftActivities' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'pepzeit_dev'
Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `externalId`, `name`, `acronym`, `rgbCode`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt` FROM `ShiftActivities` AS `ShiftActivity`;
Executing (default): SHOW INDEX FROM `Shifts`
Executing (default): SHOW INDEX FROM `ShiftActivities`
findAll:
--
  newAction
--
Executing (1cba25d7-8fb9-4fdc-a161-2133f5509985): START TRANSACTION;
Executing (default): INSERT INTO `ShiftActivities` (`id`,`externalId`,`name`,`acronym`,`rgbCode`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?);
Executing (1cba25d7-8fb9-4fdc-a161-2133f5509985): ROLLBACK;
Error:
    at Query.run (D:\server\node_modules\sequelize\src\dialects\mysql\query.js:46:25)
    at D:\server\node_modules\sequelize\src\sequelize.js:650:28
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at MySQLQueryInterface.insert (D:\server\node_modules\sequelize\src\dialects\abstract\query-interface.js:795:21)
    at ShiftActivity.save (D:\server\node_modules\sequelize\src\model.js:4153:35)
    at Function.create (D:\server\node_modules\sequelize\src\model.js:2305:12)
    at D:\server\src\database\shift-activity\shift-activity.service.ts:65:25
    at D:\server\node_modules\sequelize\src\sequelize.js:1196:18
    at ShiftsActivityService.create (D:\server\src\database\shift-activity\shift-activity.service.ts:63:11)
    at ShiftsActivityService.init (D:\server\src\database\shift-activity\shift-activity.service.ts:23:7) {
  name: 'SequelizeDatabaseError',
  parent: Error: Data truncated for column 'id' at row 1
      at Packet.asError (D:\server\node_modules\mysql2\lib\packets\packet.js:728:17)
      at Execute.execute (D:\server\node_modules\mysql2\lib\commands\command.js:29:26)
      at Connection.handlePacket (D:\server\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:497:34)
      at PacketParser.onPacket (D:\server\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:97:12)
      at PacketParser.executeStart (D:\server\node_modules\mysql2\lib\packet_parser.js:75:16)
      at Socket.<anonymous> (D:\server\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:104:25)
      at Socket.emit (node:events:526:28)
      at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)
      at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:289:9)
      at Socket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:228:10) {
    code: 'WARN_DATA_TRUNCATED',
    errno: 1265,
    sqlState: '01000',
    sqlMessage: "Data truncated for column 'id' at row 1",
    sql: 'INSERT INTO `ShiftActivities` (`id`,`externalId`,`name`,`acronym`,`rgbCode`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?);',
    parameters: [
      '4bda37b3-4b9f-4bbc-96a2-06ad233df36a',
      -1,
      'Verkauf',
      'V',
      '00ff00',
      '2023-07-06 14:09:27',
      '2023-07-06 14:09:27'
    ]
  },
  original: Error: Data truncated for column 'id' at row 1
      at Packet.asError (D:\server\node_modules\mysql2\lib\packets\packet.js:728:17)
      at Execute.execute (D:\server\node_modules\mysql2\lib\commands\command.js:29:26)
      at Connection.handlePacket (D:\server\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:497:34)
      at PacketParser.onPacket (D:\server\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:97:12)
      at PacketParser.executeStart (D:\server\node_modules\mysql2\lib\packet_parser.js:75:16)
      at Socket.<anonymous> (D:\server\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:104:25)
      at Socket.emit (node:events:526:28)
      at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)
      at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:289:9)
      at Socket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:228:10) {
    code: 'WARN_DATA_TRUNCATED',
    errno: 1265,
    sqlState: '01000',
    sqlMessage: "Data truncated for column 'id' at row 1",
    sql: 'INSERT INTO `ShiftActivities` (`id`,`externalId`,`name`,`acronym`,`rgbCode`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?);',
    '00ff00',
    '2023-07-06 14:09:27',
    '2023-07-06 14:09:27'
  ]
}
-------------------------------------
 Error:

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')
    at D:\server\src\database\shift-activity\shift-activity.service.ts:29:33
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at ShiftsActivityService.init (D:\server\src\database\shift-activity\shift-activity.service.ts:23:7)
```

The "activityTable" is injected and like I saied, the findAll() is working just fine. Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

I found it:
the "type: DataType.UUIDV4" was wrong and so sequelize decided to use number instead.

```
@Table
export class ShiftActivity extends Model{
  @Column({
    allowNull: false,
    autoIncrement: true,
    primaryKey:true,
    type: DataType.UUID, //was type: DataType.UUIDV4,
    defaultValue: DataType.UUIDV4,
  })
  id: string;
```